# select value not getting changed using jQuery and Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have two Dropdowns City and Zipcode in my form. When a Zipcode is selected by the user, I want to change the City Dropdown to the appropriate City w.r.t Zipcode. I am trying to accomplish this using Ajax.

jQuery Code:

```
$(document).on('change','#zip_id', function(e){
e.preventDefault(); 
var zipID = jQuery(this).val();
if(zipID){
jQuery.ajax({
    url: ajaxschoolajax.ajaxurl,
    data: {'zip_id': zipID, 'action':'cityOptions_Process'},
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(data){
        jQuery('#temp').html(data); 
},

error: function (exception) {
    console.log("Error");
            console.log(exception);
        }
});
```

PHP Function

```
    function cityOptions_Process() {
    if(isset($_POST["zip_id"]) && !empty($_POST["zip_id"])){
        $selectedZip = $_POST["zip_id"];
        global $wpdb;

        $sql = "SELECT `city_id` FROM `wp_gj73yj2g8h_hills_zipcodes` WHERE zip_id = '$selectedZip'";
        $data = $wpdb->get_row($sql);
        $output = $data->city_id;
        echo $output;
        die();
}
}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_cityOptions_Process', 'cityOptions_Process' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_cityOptions_Process', 'cityOptions_Process' );
```

[image: Showing Inappropriate Data]

Inappropriate responseText Ajax data showing in Ajax Error function

Comment: what is value of variable `city` in success function? also share html of select element.

Comment: I am receiving as undefined

Comment: Here is the link: http://accessrealtytampa.com/hillsborough-county-homes-school

Comment: That is where the problem is. you need to make this return correct value in php function

Comment: Now it's returning as 0

Comment: I can not help you with php code. i work in asp.net

Answer (score 1):

First of all check the value of city may be your query is not returning the valid value. After that you can simply use this code to set the drop down value.

```
 $('#city_id').val(city);
```

Also remove single quotes from data

```
 data: {zip_id: zipID, action:'cityOptions_Process'},
```

Comment: I have missed adding add_action functionality. Now I am able to see the data in my console log. It comes in the form of ":{"city_id":"8"}0" . Am confused with the 0 . I am updating my question with the present scenerio

Comment: Alright so the problem is that you are returning the complete row from your function.Your problem will be solved if you just send the value of `city_id`like `$city_id = $data->city_id;` then `echo $city_id;` and there is no need to change in the view. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I am able to see the correct data. But the problem is everytime the 0 gets appended to the result. I am wondering if this is due to some Cache Problem?

Comment: I do not think its a cache problem but you can give it a try. Can you share the updated view of results?

Comment: I added die() after an echo statement. I understood that 0 is the default value of Wordpress Ajax Admin. I will update my code. Many Thanks for helping me :)

Comment: I am happy that it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Do not echo the $cityId, return it.

```
function cityOptions_Process() {
if(isset($_POST["zip_id"]) && !empty($_POST["zip_id"])){
    $selectedZip = $_POST["zip_id"];
    global $wpdb;
    $cityId = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb_prepare("select city_id from `wp_gj73yj2g8h_hills_zipcodes` WHERE zip_id=%d",$selectedZip));
    return $cityId;

}
}
```

also remove the `select` in `$("#city_id select").val('city');`